# Python, make a chore list without the same output twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
names = ['Gio', 'Dano', 'Gian']
chores = [ 'Dookies', 'Restroom', 'Floor']
name = random.choice (names)
chore = random.choice (chores)
phrase = name + '' + chore +''
print (phrase)
```

I want this to be a random selection to end up like Gio Dookies, Dano Floor, Gian Restroom randomly randomly randomly etc. Thank you

Comment: Is for example `"Gian Dookies"` and `"Gio Dookies"` valid output?

Comment: GianDookies is valid

Comment: But are `"Gian Dookies"` and `"Gio Dookies"` valid together? Or every name can only has one chore?

Comment: Okay, so what is the issue with the code that you wrote? How is the result different from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use random.shuffle to shuffle the list of chores (no need to shuffle the names). Then, for each index in the names list, print the name at this index together with the chore at the index.

When your requirements are more complex (size of names and chores doesn't match, pairings of name/chore shouldn't repeat etc.) you need a more complex algorithm, of course.

Comment: If possible could you give me an example of how you would do it.  I am not sure what an index is because I haven't learned about it yet.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1663807/6387948 to see how you can iterate through parallel arrays. But if you're at a really novice level with Python programming, going through tutorials may be more effective than asking people to tell you solutions to individual problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can first shuffle the list of `chores` to ensure the order is random, and then `pop` elements from this list one by one (therefore returning them, while also dropping them from the list [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)). For example:

```py
import random
names = ['Gio', 'Dano', 'Gian']
chores = [ 'Dookies', 'Restroom', 'Floor']
random.shuffle(chores) # this shuffles inplace, so no need to reassign
for name in names:
    chore = chores.pop() # returns the last element of the chores
    phrase = name + ' ' + chore +' '
    print (phrase)
```

This will effectively assign every one of your `names` (people) to a chore in the list of chores. It's useful because you can also have duplicate chores (for example you need 2 people to do the "Floor"), and that can be reflected in your list from which you `pop()`.